# How to put data from database in a select box

Tags: php

I have a select box to gather the id numbers from the database, it's showing how much is in the database but the options are blank.

This is the code I have. I just want to be able to bring id number from my database in this select box.

php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "volunteer");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM registrations";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<option value=" . $rows['idnumber'] . "></option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to put a value between the `><` in `></option>`, just the same as you have included the idnumber.

Comment: `echo "<option value=" . $rows['idnumber'] . "></option>";` needs to be replaced with `echo "<option value=" . $rows['idnumber'] . ">$rows['idnumber']</option>";`

Comment: [<option>: The HTML Option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option): `echo "<option>" . $rows['idnumber'] . "</option>";` Enclose your `while` loop in `<select></select>`